# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „Dunkelheit“ und „Finsternis“?

Tags: meaning, difference, word-choice

Beides bedeutet *darkness*, aber gibt es einen Unterschied?

Ist *Finsternis* negativer, oder bösartig? Zum Beispiel gibt es diesen Satz in der *Unendlichen Geschichte* von Michael Ende:

> *[…] was ihn umgab, war nicht mehr die frostige Finsternis des Speichers, sondern ein samtenes, warmes Dunkel […]*.

Oder sind sie ganz gleich?

---

Hintergrundinformationen zum Beispiel aus dem Buch:

Bastian (der Protagonist) sitzt auf dem Schulspeicher und liest das Buch *die Unendliche Geschichte*. Die einzige Lichtquelle sind Kerzen. Dann, nach verschiedene Veranstaltungen:

> *[…] die Kerzenflammen des siebenarmigen Leuchters tanzten und legten sich
>   waagrecht, und dann fuhr ein zweiter, noch gewaltigerer Sturmwind in
>   das Buch hinein und die Lichter erloschen.*

Dann ein bisschen später:

> *Er konnte nicht den geringsten Lichtschein sehen, aber was ihn umgab,
>   war nicht mehr die frostige Finsternis des Speichers, sondern ein
>   samtenes, warmes Dunkel, in dem er sich geborgen und glücklich
>   fühlte.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wenn man sich die häufigen Bedeutungen der jeweiligen substantivierten Adjektive näher betrachtet, kann man den Unterschied beider durchaus auch synonym zu verwendenden Begriffe erahnen:

> **[finster](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/finster)**
>    1. [sehr] dunkel, **ohne Licht**
>    2. dunkel, düster erscheinend und dadurch unheimlich
>    3. anrüchig, zwielichtig
>    4. verdüstert, unfreundlich, feindselig wirkend
>
> **[dunkel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dunkel)**
>    1. a) nicht hell, nicht oder nur unzulänglich erhellt, **[fast] ohne Licht**, b) düster, unerfreulich
>    2. nicht hell, sondern von intensiver Färbung, ins Schwärzliche spielend
>    3. (von Klängen, Tönen) tief, gedämpft; nicht hell
>    4. a) unbestimmt, undeutlich b) unklar
>    5. (abwertend) undurchsichtig, verdächtig, zweifelhaft

So ist mit *finster* und der *Finsternis* immer eine stärker ausgeprägte oder totale *Dunkelheit* gemeint. Zusätzlich schwingt vielleicht auch deshalb der *Finsternis* noch die Bedeutung des *Unheimlichen*, *Feindseligen* mit. Dies fehlt bei der *Dunkelheit* in der Regel.

Answer (score 8):

*Finsternis* ist eine Art Steigerung von *Dunkelheit*. Während *Dunkelheit* bedeutet, dass einfach wenig Licht vorhanden ist, deutet das Wort *Finternis* auf das vollständige Fehlen einer jeglichen Lichtquelle hin.

Daher ist es bei Vollmond schlicht *dunkel*. Gehst du aber bei Neumond durch einen Wald herrscht *Finsternis* um dich herum.

---

Bzgl. Kontext *Die unendliche Geschichte*:

Nach dem die Lichter im Speicher erloschen waren, befindet sich der Protagonist in einer kalten, unheimlichen Umgebung (ein Speicher ist wohl alles andere als ein schöner Aufenthaltsort), umgeben von einer *völligen Dunkelheit* bzw. *Finsternis*.

Im nächsten Moment befindet er sich aber nicht mehr an dem Ort, sondern inmitten eines Nichts, wo aber eine Stimme (die der Kaiserin) zu ihm spricht. Die Stimme ist hier die „Lichtquelle“, die ihm alle Ängste nimmt. Er fühlt sich in der fremden Umgebung wohl, da er nicht alleine ist und jemanden hat, dem er Vertrauen schenkt. Daher ist die *frostige Finsternis des Speichers* gewichen, anstatt derer eine *samtige, warme Dunkelheit* ihn umgab.

> Alle Angst und Beklemmung war von ihm gefallen. Er erinnerte sich nur noch daran, wie an etwas längst Vergangenes. Ihm war so heiter und leicht zumut, dass er sogar leise lachte. […] Er hörte sie [die Stimme] ganz nah und hätte doch nicht sagen können, aus welcher Richtung sie kam: „Hier bin ich, mein Bastian.“

Comment: Ist es wirklich so? In der Beispiel oben, gibt ein bisschen Licht im Speicher, denn der Protagonist kann das Buch lesen, aber später wenn er in das "samtenes, warmes Dunkel" ist, kann er überhaupt nicht sehen.

Comment: @Cucu Die Worte für sich alleinstehend: Ja. - Ich habe versucht, basierend auf meine schwache Erinnerung an die Story, eine Interpretation anzudeuten, wie diese Wörter im Kontext verwendet werden. Sie sind hier mit Sicherheit mit einer figurativen Bedeutung unterlegt. Für die Verwendung im Kontext müsste ich aber mir die Story nochmal genauer ansehen.

Comment: Ich habe die Frage mit der Vorgeschichte ergänzt. So ich glaube wörtlich kann Finsternis dunkler als Dunkel(heit) sein, aber in diesem Fall hat Takkat recht: Finsternis bedeutet auch Unheimlich und Feindselig.

Comment: @Cucu Ich hab meine Interpretation auch nochmal überarbeitet.

Comment: @Cucu Bzgl. Takkat's Antwort. Bezogen auf das Adjektiv *finster* stimmt das. *Finsternis* selbst suggeriert aber nur das Gefühl, beschreibt es aber nicht ansich. Die Definition des Wortes *Finsternis* ist nur *völlige Dunkelheit*.

Comment: Aber noch später fragt Bastian "Warum ist es so dunkel, Mondenkind?" Das heißt es ist dunkel auch mit Mondenkind und ihre Stimme. Kann es nicht sein dass *Finsternis* erbte die Sekundärbedeutung "unheimlich, unfreundlich" von *finster*?

Comment: Ich meine auch du sprichst in eine übertragenen Sinne und nicht wörtlich wenn du sagst die Stimme ist die Lichtquelle was die Finsterniss zur Dunkelheit transformiert.

Comment: @Cucu Natürlich ist es immer noch dunkel. Wenn du nur eine Kerze anzündest, ist es ja immer noch dunkel. Hell ist es erst, wenn du ausreichend viele Lichtquellen oder ausreichend starke Lichtquellen hast, die den Raum erhellen können. - Nein, Finsternis hat diese Sekundärbedeutung nicht zwigend inne. Man spricht zum Beispiel von einer Sonnenfinsternis und verbindet dies (heutzutage) nicht mit etwas negativen. Dennoch, früher mag man bei Sonnenfinsternis vielleicht Angst gehabt haben, dass die Sonne nie wieder erleuchtet ;)

Comment: a) Wenn Dunkelheit verschiedene Abstufung von "nicht mehr hell" bis "komplett schwarz" umfasst, dann kann "finster" keine Steigerung davon sein, sondern allenfalls eine Teilmenge am Rande des Extrems. So kommt es dann auch, dass es einem Autoren freisteht die absolute Düsternis als Dunkel zu bezeichnen. b) Aus dem beleuchteten Haus kommend kann ich einen mondbeschienenen Waldweg auch als finster bezeichnen.

Comment: Achtung bei Düsternis, kann auch einen Gemütszustand beschreiben!

Answer (score 7):

Ich glaube, es ist eine Frage von Färbung. Ich gehe hier auf die Adjektive ein, denn die sind jeweils die Wurzel.

**Dunkel** ist wertneutral, **finster** nicht. **Finster** hat eine leicht negative Konnotation und passt gut zu Worten wie **kalt, leer, bedrohlich**. Ein positives Wort wie **warm** oder **beruhigend** passt dagegen nicht so ganz so gut. Zu dem neutralen **dunkel** passt alles.

Die Frage, wie viel Licht herrscht, spielt glaube ich eine untergeordnete Rolle. Dennoch würde ich sagen, dass die Mehrheit der Deutschen finster als dunkler als dunkel einordnen würden, wenn sie sich entscheiden müssten.

Comment: Schön formuliert. 1+ Besonders gefällt mir "dunkler als dunkel" (lach).

Answer (score 3):

**In Ergänzung zu Takkats Antwort:**

Es gibt den Begriff *Sonnenfinsternis*, nicht aber *Sonnendunkelheit*.

Wer eine Sonnenfinsternis erlebt hat, weiß, dass

- es bei einer Sonnenfinsternis nicht vollständig dunkel wird, es herscht ein eigentümliches Zwielicht und
- die Tiere bei Eintritt der Sonnenfinsternis verstummen, was durch das nahezu schlagartige Verstummen eine eigentümliche Situation verursacht, man könnte es auch unheimlich nennen. Jemand (ich weiß nicht mehr, wer das war) schrieb dazu: „Die Natur hält den Atem an“.

Da dieses Naturschauspiel [Sonnenfinsternis](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnenfinsternis) genannt wird, wird der Aspekt des Unheimlichen betont (obwohl es nicht vollständig dunkel (finster) ist. Wie sehr eine Sonnenfinsternis die Menschen in der Antike in Angst und Schrecken versetzte, ist im [Wikipediaartikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnenfinsternis) nachzulesen.